# Present SWRevealViewController When WebView link is tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a MainViewController with webViewMain.

The following functions checks if a link is ready to send a user to a certain directory in my webview.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    NSString *path = [url path];

    if ([path isEqualToString:@"/mypath/"]){

            NSLog(path);

        return NO; }

    return YES;
}
```

That code is all working fine. However, when the link is tapped I want to show my SWReveal Sidebar (sw_rear) and display the URL in that ViewController.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding your scenario 100%, but with luck these steps will get you where you need to be.

Fetch the revealer and the rear view controller that holds your target webview:

```
SWRevealViewController *revealer = self.revealViewController; // 'self' here should be a view controller
UIViewController *rearVC = revealer.rearViewController;
UIWebView *webview = rearVC.webView;
```

Load up your URL:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```