# Loading a url in a already loaded UIWebView swift

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift

I am using swift with XCode 6 beta and I am currently using the SWRevealController as a library for using the slide out menu.  However I am trying to load a url to the front viewcontroller from the rearviewcontroller.  I have come across a solution that used pointers in objective C, but that does not translate to swift.

This is the example I am referring too.

[Present SWRevealViewController When WebView link is tapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942827/present-swrevealviewcontroller-when-webview-link-is-tapped)

The way it is setup is the main viewcontroller that has to segue to two other view controllers one having a segue id as sw_rear and the other id as segue as sw_front.